# Yii not detecting camel case actions

Tags: php, yii, yii2, camelcasing

Yii is giving me `404 Error` if I declare an action like this:

SiteController.php

```
public function actionRegisterUser()
```

This is how I call it in the `main.php`

```
 ['label' => 'Register User', 'url' => ['/site/RegisterUser']],
```

---

I tried several different combinations. The only combination that will work is this naming convention in both places:

```
 public function actionRegisteruser

 'url' => ['/site/registeruser']
```

I used to work on another Yii project (Yii 1.0) and I could name my actions in camel case and call them without any problem. **Do I need to turn on some sort of setting to do this**?

*I also tried playing with the `rules` of the Controller but that didn't solve anything.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In some cases you need camelcase link. For example, for SEO purposes (keep inbound links). You could create rewrite rule on web server side or add inline rule to URL manager on app side. Example:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'rules' => [
        '<controller:RegisterUser>/<action:\w+>'=>'register-user/<action>',
    ],
],
```

Also it's possible to write custom [URL rule](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/runtime-routing.md#creating-rule-classes-). Example:

```
namespace app\components;

use yii\web\UrlRuleInterface;
use yii\base\Object;

class CarUrlRule extends Object implements UrlRuleInterface
{

    public function createUrl($manager, $route, $params)
    {
        if ($route === 'car/index') {
            if (isset($params['manufacturer'], $params['model'])) {
                return $params['manufacturer'] . '/' . $params['model'];
            } elseif (isset($params['manufacturer'])) {
                return $params['manufacturer'];
            }
        }
        return false;  // this rule does not apply
    }

    public function parseRequest($manager, $request)
    {
        $pathInfo = $request->getPathInfo();
        if (preg_match('%^(\w+)(/(\w+))?$%', $pathInfo, $matches)) {
            // check $matches[1] and $matches[3] to see
            // if they match a manufacturer and a model in the database
            // If so, set $params['manufacturer'] and/or $params['model']
            // and return ['car/index', $params]
        }
        return false;  // this rule does not apply
    }
}
```

And use the new rule class in the [[yii\web\UrlManager::rules]] configuration:

```
[
    // ...other rules...

    [
        'class' => 'app\components\CarUrlRule', 
        // ...configure other properties...
    ],
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify your action like this `['/site/register-user']`. As [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-controllers.html#inline-actions) says about *Inline Actions*:

> `index` becomes `actionIndex`, and `hello-world` becomes `actionHelloWorld`