# Yii2 Camel Case Controller showing 404 Not Found on Linux Server

Tags: php, linux, windows, yii2

After configuring my Yii2 application on linux server when I am trying to open controller with name like "UserProfile" (Camel Case) then it showing error of 404 not found.

Ex:

```
Not Found (#404)
Page not found.
The above error occurred while the Web server was processing your request.

Please contact us if you think this is a server error. Thank you.
```

But the controller without any camel cases are working fine.

I'm facing this issue only on linux server. On my local window machine its working fine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Yii not detecting camel case actions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32068995/yii-not-detecting-camel-case-actions)

Comment: Can it be 'user-profile'?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that on Windows you have a case-insensitive environment, while on Linux you have a case-sensitive environment. You need to use the exact string to make sure it works on Linux as well. It is a good practice to use exact strings.

Comment: Do I need to change all my controllers name?

Comment: You need to make sure that whenever there is a file path you intend to use, you are referring to all folder names and the file name in the path with exact strings. If you have a file in a folder, like foobar/LoremIpsum.php, then under Linux you will not be able to refer to it in a different way. For instance, FooBar/loremipsum.php would match under Windows, but would not match under Linux.

Comment: I got that but currently its practically difficult for me to change name of folders and files of my application so is there any way to solve this?

Comment: This should not be as difficult as you describe. If you need to change 100 strings, that can be done in an hour. If you need to do some researching as well, then you can add another hour to your estimation. If this would be more difficult, then you can ask a separate question here about how to detect and automatically change these. But that is an extreme situation, when it is cheaper to invest a few hours to do this automatically than to effectively make the changes manually. If you need to do this automatically, make sure you give me the link of the new question.